# bbpress plugin moderation

Tags: bbpress, moderation

I am using the bbpress wordpress plugin for the first time and I can't see any settings for moderation. Does bbpress have moderation built in? I did a search for any moderation plugins but only found one for the standalone version. Is there a way to enable moderation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for the same.
I just found this, not tried yet but seems to be working:
[bbPressModeration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpressmoderation/)

Comment: yep they finally updated it